# Javascript add callback function to passed callback variable

Tags: javascript

I've created a confirm dialog function that accepts a function which will be triggered when the user clicks "accept".

Now I would like to add a callback to this passed function so I can render a loader of some kind to let the user know the system is working on the response.

Here's the code so far;

```js
confirmDialog('Confirm deletion', 'Are you sure you want to delete the internet?', function(){alert('test');});

function closeConfirmDialog() {
  var dialog = document.getElementById('confirmDialog');
  var overlay = document.getElementById('dialogOverlay');
  if (dialog) { document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].removeChild(dialog); }
  if (overlay) { document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].removeChild(overlay); }
}
function confirmDialog(title, message, confirmCallback) {
  // Closing any active confirmDialog 
  closeConfirmDialog();
  // Create all required elements for the dialog box
  var dialogOverlay = document.createElement('div');
  var dialogBox = document.createElement('div');
  var buttonBox = document.createElement('div');
  var titleBox = document.createElement('div');
  var textBox = document.createElement('div');
  var cancelButton = document.createElement('a');
  var successButton = document.createElement('a');
  // Add classes/content to elements
  dialogOverlay.setAttribute('id', 'dialogOverlay');
  dialogOverlay.onclick = function () { closeConfirmDialog(); };
  dialogBox.setAttribute('id', 'confirmDialog');
  buttonBox.className = 'buttonBox';
  titleBox.className = 'titleBox';
  titleBox.innerHTML = title;
  textBox.className = 'textBox';
  textBox.innerHTML = message;
  cancelButton.className = 'dangerbtn left';
  cancelButton.innerHTML = 'Cancel';
  cancelButton.onclick = function () { closeConfirmDialog(); };
  successButton.className = 'successbtn right';
  successButton.innerHTML = 'Confirm';
  /**
         * This is where I would like to modify the confirmCallback function to always show a loader.
         */
  // Here is where I set the callback to the successButton onclick event.
  successButton.onclick = confirmCallback;
  // Add all elements to their respective wrappers
  buttonBox.appendChild(cancelButton);
  buttonBox.appendChild(successButton);
  dialogBox.appendChild(titleBox);
  dialogBox.appendChild(textBox);
  dialogBox.appendChild(buttonBox);
  // Append the overlay and finished confirmbox to the body.
  document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].appendChild(dialogBox);
  document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].appendChild(dialogOverlay);

  return false;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}
#confirmDialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#confirmDialog>.titleBox {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#confirmDialog>.textBox {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#confirmDialog>.buttonBox {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 -10px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
#confirmDialog>.buttonBox>.dangerbtn {
  background-color: #d9534f;
  border-color: #d9534f;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#confirmDialog>.buttonBox>.successbtn {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-color: #5cb85c;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you would invoke `confirmDialog`?

Comment: It's in the snippet; confirmDialog('Confirm deletion', 'Are you sure you want to delete the internet?', function(){alert('test');});

Comment: So, instead of `alert(test)` write the stuff you need (display the loader etc)

Comment: Every single time it's invoked in the project?

Comment: If you want the loader to be shown for all dialogs, then add it to the event handler: `successButton.onclick = function() { loader(); setTimeout(confirmCallback,1) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to show a loader (and nothing in the passed callback should care about it), change this line `successButton.onclick = confirmCallback;` to:

```
successButton.onclick = function() {
  confirmCallback();
  showLoader();
}
```

But if you want to pass some data into callback (and it may be a showLoader function, if you want to have some logic in the callback) — just pass it into your callback, like this:

```
successButton.onclick = function() {
  confirmCallback(showLoader);
}
```

But don't forget to call it in your callback!

Comment: Ah, yes. I completely forgot to add the parenthesis to the confirmCallback variable... Accepting answer in a minute. Thanks!